# Get default lead owner in Apex

Tags: leads, tasks

I'am creating task for inactive leads. However, there is a scenario where the lead owner is inactive already. Since 'Assigned to' field in task is a required field, I'm trying to set the default lead owner as the task owner but I haven't find any doc to get this. Is anyone here know how to achieve this or is there any other workaround on this. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

So, while I don't think there is a way to query for the default Lead Owner (you would expect it to be in the [LeadConfigSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_leadconfigsettings.htm)) you could do the following:

- Take the parent Lead and rerun the Assignment rules on that Lead. This will assign the lead to an active user
- Query the lead post-assignment rules execution to get the `Lead.OwnerId` and use for the Task

Alternatively, if your Lead Assignment rules are don't have an "otherwise" final rule, construct a temporary `Lead` with data such that you know it will fall through the entire set of assignment rules (I once used Leads coming from `Country = Diego Garcia`), thus being assigned to the default lead owner. Query the Lead for the ownerId, then delete the temporary Lead and use the ownerId for the Task

Lastly, and an approach a lot of people would do is to define the username of the default lead owner in a custom setting, label, or custom metadata and query that user to get the ID.